# Is it possible to prompt another wallet to add to a PSBT and finalize it?

Tags: wallet, bip174-psbt

Is there anyway to request a wallet to complete a PSBT?

Let's assume I want my client to send a transaction with follow structure:

- output[0]: OP_RETURN with bytes 636363636363
- output[1]: SEGWIT output, with 1000000 satoshi to my address

The scenario I'm thinking is that I generate a PSBT, generate these two outputs, and send the PSBT to my client. He import it in his wallet, wallet add inputs (and output to his address if necessary, as change box) then sign and send the transaction.

Is this scenario possible? if not, any alternatives?

Comment: Hi, I attempted to better summarize your question in the title. Please feel free to roll back or improve the title if it doesn’t match your intended question.